# How do you swap ETH with web3.js or ethers.js and uniswap v3?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, uniswap, swaps, uniswapv3

I have been successfully swapping erc20 tokens using the `exactInputSingle` method, but I can't figure out how to do a swap with ETH on either side of the swap and I can't find it in the docs or anywhere else..

I've tried using the `multicall` function with wrapETH and unwrapWETH9 but I always get STF errors when doing so.

Any help or an example would be so greatly appreciated, I've been stuck for a very long time.

Comment: `STF` means that SafeTransferFrom failed: either you don't have the correct approvals, or insufficient amounts in wallet.

Answer (score 1):

to swap token, you have to interact with the swapRouterContract and allow that contract to get ether out of your wallet. For this, you need to use `ERC20` contract's `approve` function to allow `swapRouterContract`. First step is create an `ERC20` contract

```
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(URL)
  // this is goerli
  // https://goerli.etherscan.io/token/0xb4fbf271143a4fbf7b91a5ded31806e42b2208d6
  // you could find erc20 abi online
  addressOfWeth="0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6"
  const ERC20Contract = new ethers.Contract(addressOfWeth, ERC20ABI, provider);
```

then you have to call the `approve`

```
await ERC20Contract
    // connectedWallet is the signer
    .connect(connectedWallet)
    // define approvalAmount
    .approve(swapRouterAddress, approvalAmount)


// https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/deployments
const swapRouterAddress = "0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564";
```